# Testing - how to create Mock object

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking

I am just wondering how can I create Mock object to test code like:

```
public class MyTest
{
  private A a;
  public MyTest()
  {
     a=new A(100,101);
  }
}
```

?

Thanks

Comment: So, you want to mock `A`? Is `A` doing something complex or unrepeatable that requires it to be mocked?

Comment: Yep, there's nothing to mock. You're just doing object initialization in the costructor...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Code that instantiates objects using `new` directly makes testing difficult. By using the [Factory pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) you move the creation of the object outside of the code to be tested. This gives you a place to inject a mock object and/or mock factory.

> Note that your choice of `MyTest` as the class to be tested is a bit unfortunate as the name implies that it is the test itself. I'll change it to `MyClass`. Also, creating the object in the constructor could easily be replaced by passing in an instance of `A` so I'll move the creation to a method that would be called later.

```
public interface AFactory
{
    public A create(int x, int y);
}

public class MyClass
{
    private final AFactory aFactory;

    public MyClass(AFactory aFactory) {
        this.aFactory = aFactory;
    }

    public void doSomething() {
        A a = aFactory.create(100, 101);
        // do something with the A ...
    }
}
```

Now you can pass in a mock factory in the test that will create a mock `A` or an `A` of your choosing. Let's use Mockito to create the mock factory.

```
public class MyClassTest
{
    @Test
    public void doSomething() {
        A a = mock(A.class);
        // set expectations for A ...
        AFactory aFactory = mock(AFactory.class);
        when(aFactory.create(100, 101)).thenReturn(a);
        MyClass fixture = new MyClass(aFactory);
        fixture.doSomething();
        // make assertions ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Emm... in the case of "factory" pattern should I do constructor private ?

Comment: @user592704 - No because the factory that instantiates `A` must be able to access the constructor.

Answer (score 3):

Using `mockito` mcking framework, try something like below:

```
   whenNew(MyTest.class)
     .withArguments(Mockito.anyInt(), Mockito.anyInt())
     .thenReturn(new MockedMyTest(param1, param2));
```

Comment: I don't think he should pass constructor arguments to MyClass.class.

Answer (score 2):

Use an interface Ia;
Then.

```
Class A implements Ia;
Class MockA implements Ia;
private Ia a;
```

Then

```
public MyMockTest {
a = new MockA(100, 100);
int result = a.doWork();
assertEquals(200, result);
 // asuming doWork would add both constructor parameters
}
```