# Mockito testcase for method.invoke()

Tags: java, junit, mockito

How should I write a Mockito JUnit testcase for this Java code?

```
Method[] methods = Sample.class.getMethods();
for (Method method : methods) {
    method.invoke(null)
}
```

Comment: What do you want to test? That the method `invoke` was called?

Comment: why are you testing Java Reflection API?

Answer (score 0):

Try looking on these sites.

[Invoking Methods using Method Object](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-reflection/methods.html)
[Reflection to call Java method](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-use-reflection-to-call-java-method-at-runtime/)

Answer (score 0):

You can try writing mockito junit for this method itself, rather api specific 
junits

Refer: [Testing - how to create Mock object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13597269/testing-how-to-create-mock-object)